# how to call email validation function in button click using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

hi I have got email validation function like this below

```
protected void cvEmail_OnServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
    User objUser = new User();
    string strEmail = txtEmail.Text.Trim();
    //   strEmail = "'" + strEmail + "'";
   string strERROR = objUser.IsEmailExists(strEmail, true);
     if (strERROR.Equals(string.Empty))
    {
        //bool passed = true;
        e.IsValid = true;
        if (objUser.IsEmailExistsSSO(strEmail))
        {
            hdnDuplicate.Value = "true";
        }

        else if (objUser.IsRestrictedDomain(strEmail,true))
        {
            e.IsValid = false;
            ((CustomValidator)sender).ErrorMessage = "This Email Id is found in our list of Restricted Domain";
        }
        if (userIdentity == null)
        {             
            wizNewAcct.ActiveStepIndex = 2;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        e.IsValid = false;
        ((CustomValidator)sender).ErrorMessage = strERROR;
    }

}
```

my aim is I want call this function in below button click event

```
protected void btnVerifyCert_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsValid)
    {
        wizNewAcct.ActiveStepIndex = 0;
        return;
    }
    wizNewAcct.ActiveStepIndex = 1;
}
```

and below code is for button click aspx file

```
<asp:Button ID="btnVerifyCert" CssClass="btn" runat="server" OnClick="btnVerifyCert_OnClick" Text="Next &gt;&gt;" ValidationGroup="VerifyCert" />
```

code for email id

```
  <td style="width:10%">
Email Address:
</td>
<td style="width:10%">
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" MaxLength="255" Columns="50" CssClass="txt"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
<td style="width:100px">
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvEmail" runat="server" CssClass="lblError" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="You did not enter an email address" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ValidationGroup="UserInfo" Width="276px"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revEmail" runat="server" CssClass="lblError" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid email address" ControlToValidate="txtEmail"
ValidationExpression="^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\.+_-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$" Width="277px" ></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
<asp:CustomValidator id="CustomValidator1" runat="server" CssClass="lblError" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ValidationGroup="VerifyEmail"
 OnServerValidate="cvEmail_OnServerValidate" Width="278px"></asp:CustomValidator>
</td>
```

how can I call the serverside validation function in button click event

Comment: In cvEmail_OnServerValidate have you set e.IsValid = False if an error occurs?

Comment: yes I have already mentioned it in email validation function ....

Comment: @tezzo I will post full code so that it can be easily understandable.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested it but I think the problem is that `btnVerifyCert_OnClick` has `ValidationGroup="VerifyCert"` and `CustomValidator1` has `ValidationGroup="VerifyEmail"`.